# Is there an expression in "en sont on ne peut plus amoureux"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques

> S’il est vrai que le prestige de la culture française est en perte de
>   vitesse en Roumanie, en revanche les passionnés de Littérature
>   française **en sont on ne peut plus amoureux**.

I don't understand the meaning of *on ne peut* between *en sont* and *plus amoureux*. If the subject is *les passionnés*, why do we have after *en sont* (*les passionnés en sont*) this *on ne peut*, which, if I'm correct, means *one cannot* / *we cannot*.

It doesn't make any sense at this particular moment, unless I'm being helped to understand this, in my not very educated opinion, weird construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've not split the sentence correctly. The expression you are interested in here is *on ne peut plus*, meaning *extremely*, *absolutely* (literally *one can't be more*). It's a way to emphasize the following adjective, *amoureux*.

Have a look at the [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_ne_peut_plus) for extra examples.

Comment: Thank you. So the translation would be: _those passionate about French literature couldn't be more in love with it_? Where _en_ doubles... _Roumanie_?

Comment: Almost! Here, *en* refers to *la culture française*.

Comment: Oh, merci beaucoup! What about my translation? Is it correct? I just want to learn as correctly as humanly possible because I'm quite in love with French.

Comment: @indoxica Cette traduction est on ne peut plus correcte! :)

Comment: Oh, je suis très hereux maintenant! Merci!

Comment: @indoxica tu as froid?

Answer (score 0):

La phrase, malheureusement, est mal tournée. Je suppose qu'elle signifie:

"S'il est vrai que le prestige de la culture française est en baisse / diminue en Roumanie, en revanche les passionnés de la littérature française n'en sont que plus amoureux."

You can't say that "prestige", an abstract notion, is losing speed, which is mechanical.

The first formulation would suggest that because some ... there is a reaction from others in favor of ....

Comment: Mmm remplacer une expression victime d'abus par une fausse causalité… bof. Ça remains bad style — heh, switching languages in the middle of a post is disturbing, ain't it? :-)